# Multiple Google Accounts and the Market

Tags: google-play-store, accounts

I have multiple Google accounts like below:

1. Account A (my primary account).
2. Account B
3. Account C

I only have the extra two accounts for gmail (via Google Apps for domains) and don't use them for anything else.

I only want to use Account A on the market. I currently have an annoying issue where the market app keeps using Account B, so I end up downloading things to Account B by mistake.

Is there anyway I can remove these other accounts from the market or set some sort of default account?

Thanks

**Update**: I know that I can press menu in the market app and select a different account, but this is annoying because it defaults to Account B. My crazy theory is that when looking for updates (in the background), it first checks Account A and then B. Because it checked account B last it leaves that as the active one. Account C has never downloaded an app so it doesn't check for updates.

Comment: I'm having the same issue: I started with a single account (A) on my phone, added a second account (B) a few weeks later, and now the market defaults to B. As the OP said, I can manually switch via the menu, but I seem to have to do that EVERY TIME I open the market app. So I doubt that @Blundell's solution below will work, as his method is how I got into this mess in the first place. Has anyone found an app to lock in the default market account?

Comment: I don't have the time to try @Blundell's solution right now. But I will try do it in the reverse order so that I add my default account last. Although I don't think this will work as it is currently ignoring my latest Account C.

Comment: I have almost exactly the same problem, except I get update notifications from account C, which has never installed an app (I only added the account yesterday, so I'm 100% positive).   I don't know (yet), if I'll still get notifications for B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to have been fixed in version 3.3.11 and above of the market app.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to remove the other Accounts from the Market is to unsync them from the phone.

Settings > Accounts & Sync > Click the google account > Press Remove Account

Perhaps remove all three, add your Account A, load the market. Then go and add the other two accounts through Accounts & Sync and not through the market.

This *should* leave Account A as the default.