# How to change android primary google account

Tags: google-play-store, google-account, in-app-purchase

During the "in-app purchase" I am unable to switch the Google account I would like to use for "in-app purchase". Currently, in order to change the primary Google account on Android operating system, we have the following ways:

- Remove other Google accounts, leave only one Google account.
- Perform factory reset on our devices.

  - If we perform factory reset, we will lose all data that we have not backed up or unable to do backup. And, we have to re-install the applications that we need to use.

If we choose to remove other Google accounts from our systems and leave only one Google account, if there are applications installed from Google Play Store by using the Google account that we want to remove from our systems, then we will not be able to remove the account from the system unless we remove those applications. However, sometimes we may forget which account we used to install an application from Google Play Store.

My question is that is there any other way to switch between the accounts?

Comment: Have you checked for existing answers to this question? [Switch between accounts in Android 4.2](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/47689/16575) / [How to change the account for Android Market?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/4955/16575) / [Multiple Google Accounts and the Market](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/14179/16575) / [How do I change a Google account for Android mobile (Xperia 10)?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/614/16575). The last one mentions [Erazzer Free](https://market.android.com/details?id=dsoft.ErazzerFree) for this (root required).

Answer (score 5):

I believe I had a similar problem.
I just bought the Moto X on Verizon.  I linked 3 Google accounts to this phone (including my wife's to sync our calendars.)
The phone chose my wife's account as the primary so when I sent text messages they would be sent from my wife's Google account.
SOLUTION:
I went into the Google+ account app, logged out of her account and then the phone asked me which one to log into.
Problem solved to change my primary account without factory reset.

Answer (score 5):

[Here](http://www.technipages.com/android-change-main-google-account) is a good description, on how to do this. To cite the main facts:

### If your phone is NOT rooted

> If your device isn’t rooted, the only thing you can do is perform a hard reset on the device. You can normally do this under Settings > Privacy > Factory data reset. Doing this will wipe all data and settings from the device.
>
> Unfortunately, if you really need to change the main Google account, this is the only option unless you gain root access.

### If your phone is rooted

> - Navigate to the /data/system directory.
> - Tap and hold the accounts.db file, then select Rename.
> - Rename the file to accounts.db.old to make a backup of the file.
> - Restart your Android device.
> - Once the device restarts, open an app that requires a Google account such as Market, Gmail or GTalk. You will be prompted to create a new account or login using an existing account. That’s all there is to it.

Comment: Perfect if you got a rooted device

Comment: In my case i have to delete (or rename) the folder `/data/system/users` anyway is a wonderful answer

Answer (score 3):

I used the following procedure:

1. Uninstall the app
2. Go to Play Store and switch to the account you want to use to pay from
3. Using Google Play web version (you may need to login first), find the app and install again
4. Make your in-app purchase

Source: [Change Gmail account to make in-app purchase?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/70215/change-gmail-account-which-will-make-in-app-purchase)

Comment: +1, just great solution if you install custom app without app store