# In-app purchase changing account

Tags: in-app-purchase

I have 2 accounts and I have a google play card on one and none on the other... I want to use the account with the card to make the in-app purchase.. but I tried to install the app on my account with the card except when I tried it still came up on the account without the card... Please help!

Comment: Please have a look to see if the answer I gave someone else helps you: http://android.stackexchange.com/a/150165/15394